# error: Cannot format given Object as a Date, when formatting date to new format (Android)

Tags: java, android, date, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to change the format of dates that stored in a list. And then save that list of date to firebase database. But I got error when formatting the date that stored in dateList.
This is my code :

MainActivity.java

```
List<Date> dates = getDates(date1, date2);
    ArrayList<String> dateStringList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<Date>();
    SimpleDateFormat format1 =new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    for (Date date : dates) {
        String dateStr = String.valueOf(date);
        dateStringList.add(dateStr);
    }
    for (String dateString : dateStringList) {
        try {
            dateList.add(format1.parse(dateString));
            format2.format(dateList); ---> error here when formatting the date to format2
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    String date1 = format2.format(dateList);
    dateModel data = new dateModel(dateList);
    mReference.child(id).setValue(data);
```

dateModel.java

```
public class dateModel {
ArrayList<Date> date;

public dateModel() {}

public dateModel(ArrayList<Date> date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public ArrayList<Date> getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(ArrayList<Date> date) {
    this.date = date;
} 
}
```

is there a way to solved this?
thank you so much..

Comment: `dateList` is a ArrayList, put there only single Object of date String

Comment: Note: all your classes should start with capital letters in Java

Comment: By the way, you should be able to directly write a `ArrayList<Date>` to Firebase without a custom class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your code doesn't even compile.

Check your types.

The format method takes a Date, not a List and I don't see why you need two formats

```
List<Date> dates = getDates(date1, date2);
ArrayList<String> dateStringList = new ArrayList<>();

SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

for (Date date : dates) {
    try {
        dateStringList.add(fmt.format(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

dateModel data = new dateModel(dateList);
mReference.child(id).setValue(data);
```

Note that saving your list as strings probably isn't a good idea other than "visual inspection". It's the UI responsibility to format dates and times , in my opinion, and storing milliseconds (`date.getTime()`) is easier to query and filter in certain cases.

Comment: i think if i want to format a date, the first thing to do is convert it to the String and parse it in the list date. so i use two different format. but now, i understand if it can work by just use string to format it. Thanks so much for your help and answer... @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

`datelist` is an ArrayList. You cannot format an arraylist to a date.

It should be

`format2.format(dateString)`